# How to filter Intellisense, Auto Completion, in Visual Studio C#, to show only members that the Project defined?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, .net-assembly, code-completion, user-defined

How to filter Intellisense, Auto Completion, in Visual Studio C#, to show only members that the Project defined, or that are contained in the assembly from which I am currently editing code. Or that are defined in the actual class/interface that I am completing code one, and not the parent class?

Very often when I want to invoke/call/use a member that I defined. I am currently in a habbit of navigating to the class which I want to invoke a function on, copy/remember the name, then complete the code.

The thing is that I would find it very useful (in reducing redundant hand movement), while coding, to be able to view only the functionality that is written by me. Because in the environment that I am writing each object has at least 200 built in members that appear in most intellisense suggestions. And these built in suggestions are not part of my Assembly or Project. they are from the Engine. Similarly C# itself defines all these ToString() like members for each System.Object of which everything is derived from. To find the User-Defined members amongst all these System and Engine defined members is a hassle.

I searched google and forum for answers, to no avail. Also I don't have the money for solutions, so I would appreciate if it would be a free solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I afraid the answer is negative.** 
For now, IntelliSense cannot suppress the display of built-in properties, methods, and so on from the root cause to only show the custom parameter methods, and so on.

However, since **VS2017**, IntelliSense has only **added filters**, which can only be filtered by fields, methods, classes, keywords and so on.But you cannot filter by customization or built-in.

[image]

**Suggestion**

I suggest you put the class name, method naming specification(add some fields to prompt the method's role such as function **select_AllManagers**). After that, you can type a few more keywords to narrow IntelliSense down.

**In addition**, if you still want to get this point, you could report it to [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to raise the Support Team's attention. Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for validating my futile searches.